# renaming files with a particular extension

Tags: android

i am trying to rename the extensions of two types of files in my storage. The first type is ".mp3", i want to rename it to **".xmp3"** and the second one is ".mp4" to **".xmp4"**. i can delete files using this method but how do i modify it to rename files? thanks

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String Patternjpg = ".mp4";
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(Patternjpg)) {
                    // Do what ever u want
                    listFile[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about using the File.renameTo() method? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29

Comment: hello Bhargav, could you provide a snippet answer? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the file's `renameTo` method to rename files that end in the target extension.

You can generically account for any extension type by defining a group of extensions the method needs to prepend with `'x'`.

For example, the approach below does a series of replacements for the defined extensions, and then renames the file:

```
public static final String[] TARGET_EXTENSIONS = { "mp4", "mp3", "mp55", "other" };

public void walkdir(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                    fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext, ".x" + ext)
                }

                listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need a reliable method to rename atleast 10+ files

Comment: @nbrooks no she wants to replace mp3 files too thats the reason I went with indexOfDot method, its extensible if she wants more extensions to be renamed with x all she has to do is add the condition in the if statement

Comment: @Felicia sorry, forgot to remove that when I modified the code to work with other extensions

Comment: @nbrooks no shes talking about 10+ files not extensions

Comment: awesome answer, but how do i remove the "x" later?

Comment: @Felicia You can reverse the process based on the code above. Good luck!

Comment: @Bhargav Ah, not sure why I thought I saw 10+ extensions. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: out of the question, but can you tell me instead of renaming extension, how do i simply add a "." before a file name for instance, miller.jpg -> .miller.jpg         i will up vote if you help :D

Comment: @Felicia The [`renameTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) method referenced above can be used for that as well, and there's an example of how that's used in both answers here. Give it a try to see if you can figure it out. If you get stuck, post a new question showing what you've tried, and explaining what's not working. Should be pretty straightforward! :)

Comment: @Felicia first you do `String fileName = listFile[i].getName();` , which should give you the name, next you do `String fullPath = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();` to get the full path, then you do `int indexOfFileNameStart = fullPath.lastIndexOf(fileName)` , then you get a string builder instance from fullPath like so `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fullPath);` , now you call the insert method on sb `sb.insert(indexOfFileNameStart, ".")`

Comment: ha! i work so hard don't even get an upvote, life is sad :(

Comment: bhargav invite me to chat if you can , because  this code is beyond my comprehension lol

Comment: hey buddy check out my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693495/renaming-file-extensions-in-android

Answer (score 2):

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String Patternjpg = ".mp4";
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                String name = listFile[i].getName();
                if (name.endsWith("mp4") || name.endsWith("mp3")) {
                    // Do what ever u want
                    String fileName = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    int indexOfDot = fileName.indexOf(".");
                    StringBuilder newFileName = new StringBuilder(fileName);
                    newFileName.insert(indexOfDot + 1, "x");
                    listFile[i].renameTo(new File(newFileName.toString()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This might work I havent tested it, the renameTo method definitely works, but generating the new file name as you require isn't tested, just test to see if the new file string is the string you desire

**EDIT**

For your second query

> but can you tell me instead of renaming extension, how do i simply add
>   a "." before a file name for instance, miller.jpg -> .miller.jpg i
>   will up vote if you help

first you do `String fileName = listFile[i].getName();` , which should give you the name, next you do `String fullPath = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();` to get the full path, then you do `int indexOfFileNameStart = fullPath.lastIndexOf(fileName)` , then you get a string builder instance from fullPath like so `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fullPath);` , now you call the insert method on sb `sb.insert(indexOfFileNameStart, ".")`, now sb should have the string you desire, just construct it to string `sb.toString()`

Ill add this in code

```
private String putDotBeforeFileName(File file) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    int indexOfFileNameStart = fullPath.lastIndexOf(fileName);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fullPath);
    sb.insert(indexOfFileNameStart, ".");
    String myRequiredFileName = sb.toString();
    file.renameTo(new File(myRequiredFileName));
    return myRequiredFileName;
}
```

I would prefer if you posted a separate question for this, as this question has nothing to do with this answer

Comment: hey it added the "x" before the "."

Comment: @Felicia then just do indexOfDot+1

Comment: i replaced the "." with "mp4"

Comment: ah that works too ! also the answer given by nbrooks works too

Comment: `listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath.replace(MP4, XMP4)));`

Comment: @Felicia but your code should replace mp3 files too right? but it does only for mp4

Comment: then how do i add more extensions to it? i want to rename like 10+

Comment: @Felicia its simple ill edit the answer, just change the if statement that checks just for file names ending with .mp4 to also check for .mp3 with OR operator

Comment: @Felicia yea, just check the if statement i added an additional condition for endswith mp3

Comment: +1 Good Answer. I'd try to avoid the repetition when checking the extension though; you could put the name in a variable a first, for example. Just a thought :)

Comment: bhargav im upvoting your answer for the help, keep it up!

Comment: bhargav check out my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693495/renaming-file-extensions-in-android