# renaming file extensions in android

Tags: android

I am able to change file extensions, for example, from ".mp4" to ".xmp4" but instead of changing extension, i simply want to add a "." before a file name for example "**mikey.jpg**" to "**.mikey.jpg**". how do i do that?

```
public static final String[] TARGET_EXTENSIONS = { "mp4", "mp3", "mp55", "other" };

public void walkdir(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                    fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext, ".x" + ext);
                }

                listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the full code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

    // getting SDcard root path
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    walkdir(dir);
}

public static final String[] TARGET_EXTENSIONS = { "mp4", "mp3", "avi", "other" };

public void walkdir(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                    fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext, ".x" + ext);
                }

                listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

first you do `String fileName = listFile[i].getName();` , which should give you the name, next you do `String fullPath = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();` to get the full path, then you do `int indexOfFileNameStart = fullPath.lastIndexOf(fileName)` , then you get a string builder instance from fullPath like so `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fullPath);` , now you call the insert method on sb `sb.insert(indexOfFileNameStart, ".")`, now sb should have the string you desire, just construct it to string `sb.toString()`

Ill add this in code

```
private String putDotBeforeFileName(File file) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    int indexOfFileNameStart = fullPath.lastIndexOf(fileName);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fullPath);
    sb.insert(indexOfFileNameStart, ".");
    String myRequiredFileName = sb.toString();
    file.renameTo(new File(myRequiredFileName));
    return myRequiredFileName;
}
```

**EDIT**

This is how you can use the above method in your code

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();
                for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                    if(fPath.endsWith(ext)) {
                        putDotBeforeFileName(listFile[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Felicia with the full code, just copy that function and call it in your code where you want to rename, this method will also rename the File instance you pass to it, and return the fullPath of the newly created file

Comment: @Felicia check the edited answer, to see how you can use the method in your code

Comment: @Felicia keep everything else as it is just the walkDir method like I shown in my code, and add the putDotBeforeFileName method to your class

Comment: remove the dot again? its just string manipulation, get the filePath and find the index of the dot and remove it it can't be that hard I have provided with details of all the string manipulation techniques required to do this

Comment: im new to this :( snippet please?